# Why is privateKey padded before secp256k1 signing?

Tags: go-ethereum, cryptography, encryption

I am checking how the Ethereum handles signing but I can't figure out why the `math.PaddedBigBytes` is necessary:

```
func Sign(digestHash []byte, prv *ecdsa.PrivateKey) (sig []byte, err error) {
    if len(digestHash) != DigestLength {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("hash is required to be exactly %d bytes (%d)", DigestLength, len(digestHash))
    }
    seckey := math.PaddedBigBytes(prv.D, prv.Params().BitSize/8)
    defer zeroBytes(seckey)
    return secp256k1.Sign(digestHash, seckey)
}
```

Does it have to do something with the intention to generate a 65 bytes sig length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They take the private key `prv.D` and pad zeroes to the most significant Bytes of the key, so that it will have the correct length, as specified in `prv.Params().BitSize` (bits) or `prv.Params().BitSize./8` (Bytes). In that case, since we use the curve secp256k1, the private key will always we padded to 32 Bytes length.

Example:

Real private key is 0040408ca91387a405889c367fd2dc38884a15e45d7ac910bbe3db46d9b82fe5

as it seems, the developer who created that code supposed that it can be stored with the most significant Bytes truncated. If you interpret the private key as a number, this can happen, since the most significant (zero) Bytes do not change the value of the number in that case.

prv.D = 40408ca91387a405889c367fd2dc38884a15e45d7ac910bbe3db46d9b82fe5

`seckey := math.PaddedBigBytes(prv.D, prv.Params().BitSize/8)`

seckey = 0040408ca91387a405889c367fd2dc38884a15e45d7ac910bbe3db46d9b82fe5

EDIT: Changed a typo in prv.D